# Accessing array member codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, member

I want to access this arrays member named 'tag', how can i do that?
Array;

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[23]
      public 'tag' => string '20' (length=2)
```

Comment: You may need to use result_array() in your model and foreach it in your controller, and then to view

Comment: It worked, thanks. But can i access directly like this array_name['tag'] ?

Comment: In side your foreach in controller do a data array `$data['something'][] = array('name' => $result['name'])` and the on view would be `foreach ($something as $row) {echo $row['name']}` Just a idea any way not to sure what your controller says or model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u wanna access object of the array

```
$array_name->object_name;
```

if you wanna access array member

```
$array_name[array_member];
```

if the object within array memebr means use

```
$array_name[array_member]->object_name;
```